# Group object based on attributes and combine rest of the columns in a list gives me unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, pandas

I am having this object :

```
obj = [
    {"mode":1,"items":[{"id":1}],"people":[{"id":8888}],"value":{"v":1000}},
    {"mode":1,"items":[{"id":1}],"people":[{"id":8888}],"value":{"v":2000}},
    {"mode":1,"items":[{"id":1}],"people":[{"id":9999}],"value":{"v":1000}},
    {"mode":1,"items":[{"id":1}],"people":[{"id":9999}],"value":{"v":2000}}
]
```

and i want to group by `mode` and `items` and `value` and combine `people` values into a list.

So the result I want to get is :

```
resObj = [
    {"mode":1,"items":[{"id":1}],"people":[{"id":8888},{"id":9999}],"value":{"v":1000}}
    {"mode":1,"items":[{"id":1}],"people":[{"id":8888},{"id":9999}],"value":{"v":2000}}
]
```

When i do :

```
>>> obj = [{"mode":1,"items":[{"id":1}],"people":[{"id":8888}],"value":{"v":1000}},{"mode":1,"items":[{"id":1}],"people":[{"id":8888}],"value":{"v":2000}},{"mode":1,"items":[{"id":1}],"people":[{"id":9999}],"value":{"v":1000}},{"mode":1,"items":[{"id":1}],"people":[{"id":9999}],"value":{"v":2000}}]

>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(obj)
>>> df.groupby(['items','mode','value'])['people'].apply(list)
```

i get `unhashable type: 'list'`

This is expected as `people` is a list, but how can I achieve what I want? Another problem is that "items" is also a list and I've been reading `groupby` doesn't work on unhashable types.

is there a way to achieve the transformation I need?

EDIT: I've also tried :

```
>>> df['items']=df['items'].apply(lambda x: tuple(x))
>>> df['people']=df['people'].apply(lambda x: tuple(x))
>>> df.groupby(['items','mode','value'])['people'].apply(list)
```

but now I get unhashable type `dict`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't group by columns that contain lists or dicts as they are not hashable. So in fact the `people` column is not the problem, but the columns `item` and `value` are. The easiest solution would be to convert them to strings so they can be used for grouping.

This sample shows how this can be achieved:

```
df['_items'] = df['items'].apply(lambda item: ",".join([str(x['id']) for x in item]))
df['_value'] = df['value'].apply(lambda value: value['v'])
print(df.groupby(['_items','mode','_value'])['people'].sum())
```

Output:

```
_items  mode  _value
1       1     1000      [{'id': 8888}, {'id': 9999}]
              2000      [{'id': 8888}, {'id': 9999}]
Name: people, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Complex data, e.g. `list/dict/tuple` within dataframe's cells should be avoided. That said, with your data, you can unpack the dictionaries inside the lists:

```
(df.groupby([
    'mode',
    df['items'].apply(lambda x: x[0]['id']),
    df['value'].apply(lambda x: x['v'])
], as_index=False).agg({'people':'sum',
                        'items':'first',
                        'value':'first'})
   .to_dict(orient='records')
)
```

Output:

```
[{'mode': 1, 'people': [{'id': 8888}, {'id': 9999}], 'items': [{'id': 1}], 'value': {'v': 1000}}, 
 {'mode': 1, 'people': [{'id': 8888}, {'id': 9999}], 'items': [{'id': 1}], 'value': {'v': 2000}}]
```